# Convert ISO DateTime to XMLGregorianCalendar and verify using JUnits

Tags: java, junit, java-8, isodate, xmlgregoriancalendar

I'm having a util method that converts ISO Date Format into XMLGregorianCalendar.

I'm trying to write unit test cases for it, however, I'm unable to create the expected object as that of the actual - there is time zone conversion happening in between and the objects are not matching.

```
 public static XMLGregorianCalendar convertStringToXMLGregorianCalendar(final String dateStrInXMLGregorianCalendar) {
        try {
            DateTime dateTime = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().parseDateTime(dateStrInXMLGregorianCalendar);
            GregorianCalendar gregCal = new GregorianCalendar(dateTime.getZone().toTimeZone());
            gregCal.setTimeInMillis(dateTime.getMillis());
            return DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gregCal);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Exception while converting %s to XMLGregorianCalendar!", dateStrInXMLGregorianCalendar), e);
        }
 }
```

JUnit:

```
@Test
public void testFoo() throws Exception {

     XMLGregorianCalendar result = convertStringToXMLGregorianCalendar("2016-02-06T00:00:00.000+0100");
     assertNotNull(result);
     assertTrue(result.toGregorianCalendar().toZonedDateTime().toLocalDateTime().compareTo(
                DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(2016, 2, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0).toGregorianCalendar().toZonedDateTime().toLocalDateTime()) == 0);
}
```

Comment: Works for me. By the way: I don't know why you trying so hard to mix in at least 4 different time APIs (Joda-Time, java.time, GregorianCalendar and XMLGregorianCalendar). If your input were [XML-schema-compatible with colon inside tz-offset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeFactory.html#newXMLGregorianCalendar-java.lang.String-) then you could simply do: `DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar("2016-02-06T00:00:00.000+01:00")`.

Comment: @MenoHochschild: Unfortunately, "2016-02-06T00:00:00.000+0100": This is the date format WITHOUT colon. It works fine with the colon.